# How to optimize the following code

Tags: optimization, vb6

I have a code which is redundant. Sp please help me in optimizing the code.

Basically I am feting a fetching a version number from registry. It can be in any of one of 6 path. So I am iterating like below code. I feel there can be something better than this. Please help me to optimize the below code.

```
Private Function as Integer()

'Some Code
versionnum = GetRegValue (hKey,path1,"Version","")

If versionnum = "" Then
    versionnum = GetRegValue (hKey,path2,"Version","")
EndIf

If versionnum = "" Then
    versionnum = GetRegValue (hKey,path3,"Version","")
EndIf

If versionnum = "" Then
    versionnum = GetRegValue (hKey,path4,"Version","")
EndIf

If versionnum = "" Then
    versionnum = GetRegValue (hKey,path5,"Version","")
EndIf

If versionnum = "" Then
    versionnum = GetRegValue (hKey,path6,"Version","")
EndIf

returnval = CompareVersion(Expected,versionnum)
'Some Code

End Function
```

Comment: Make an array of paths containing path1..path6 and loop.

Comment: Is it *actually* too slow? I can think of other ways to optimize it, but they are almost undoubtedly overkill.

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize" here ?

Comment: People love using words they don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Since the path is permanent, make the path an array, then loop.

btw you should CamelCase or under_score so it would be much more readable.
and ALL_CAPS on constants

I don't know VB6 but it should make sense.
It should be something like this:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
     if(versionNum == null){
         versionNum = GetRegValue (hKey,path[i],"Version","");
     }
 }

 returnval = CompareVersion(EXPECTED,versionNum)
```

Comment: You would compare inside the loop & exit when needed, else you just compare the last result.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I used the below code to optimize it,

```
For i = 1 To 6
    versionnum = GetRegValue(hKey, Choose(i, ProductKey1, ProductKey2, ProductKey3, ProductKey4, ProductKey5, ProductKey6), "displayversion", "")
    If LenB(versionnum) Then Exit For
Next
```